# Install Perl on Windows for LaTeX Packages Without Dependency Issues

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, perl, latex, chocolatey

I'm currently facing challenges with installing Perl on my Windows system, which I need for handling [specific LaTeX related packages](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/376). My journey so far has led me through a series of issues, and I'm looking for guidance on resolving them effectively.

Initially, I attempted to install **StrawberryPerl** using Chocolatey, as it's commonly recommended for LaTeX users. However, I encountered a persistent issue related to the `File::Which` dependency that I couldn't resolve

```
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring File-HomeDir-1.006 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: File::Which
--> Working on File::Which
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/P/PL/PLICEASE/File-Which-1.27.tar.gz ... OK
! Bad archive: File-Which-1.27.tar.gz
! Failed to unpack File-Which-1.27.tar.gz: no directory
! Failed to fetch distribution File-Which-1.27
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'File::Which' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for File-HomeDir-1.006.
```

The specific error during installation was related to the failure of fetching and unpacking `File::Which`. Despite several attempts, including changing CPAN mirrors and manually installing the dependency, I could not get past this problem.

Next, I shifted to trying **ActivePerl** from the ActiveState Platform. Unfortunately, this led to its own set of issues. The installation process failed mid-way, and even though I used Chocolatey for installation

```
WARNING: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\ActivePerl_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error.
ERROR: Running ["C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "C:\Users\FooBar\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\ActivePerl\5.28.0\ActivePerl-5.28.msi" /quiet TARGETDIR="C:\" PERL_PATH=Yes PERL_EXT=Yes ] was not successful. Exit code was '1603'. Exit code indicates the following: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\ActivePerl_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error..
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
The install of ActivePerl was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ActivePerl\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - ActivePerl (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ActivePerl\tools\ChocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

and it resulted in various `state.exe` files being scattered across my system in different directories (`AppData\Local` and `AppData\Roaming`). These files proved to be quite challenging to delete, with 'Access is denied' errors, complicating the situation further.

At this point, I am seeking advice on how to:

1. Successfully install Perl on Windows for LaTeX work, specifically for the package that requires `latexindent`.
2. Resolve the dependency issue encountered with StrawberryPerl, or alternatively,
3. Complete the installation of ActivePerl without the errors and subsequent file contamination.

I want to avoid falling into an XY problem by addressing the wrong part of my issue. My main goal is to have a working Perl setup that allows me to use `latexindent` for my LaTeX projects. Any insights, experiences, or recommendations on how to navigate this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When does the  1st error exactly occur? choco install, separate package install?

Comment: @Destroy666 when I try running `cpanm File::HomeDir`

Comment: Do you have manual access to http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/P/PL/PLICEASE/File-Which-1.27.tar.gz? Did you check if the file is downloaded properly? What's the version of cpanm?

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem many years ago and just gave up. Your question reminded me of this, and I managed to get it working.

1. I'm using the Miktex distribution.
2. I just installed StrawberryPerl using the MSI downloaded from their site.

I did a test from a terminal using

```
latexindent test.tex -w
```

and it worked for me.